# How to restore SQL Server 2014 database to SQL Server Express 2012

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014, sql-server-2014-express

When I try to restored DB , every time I am getting this error

TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio ------------------------------  Restore of database 'PramodDb' failed.

> (Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.RelationalEngineTasks) 
>   ------------------------------ ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:  System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: The database was backed up on a server
>   running version 12.00.4100. That version is incompatible with this
>   server, which is running version 11.00.6020. Either restore the
>   database on a server that supports the backup, or use a backup that is
>   compatible with this server. (Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtented)

Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

Like always it helps to read the error. Let me quote pretty much all of your error message:

> The database was backed up on a server running version 12.00.4100. That 
>   version is incompatible with this server, which is running version 11.00.6020. 
>   Either restore the database on a server that supports the backup, or use a
>   backup that is compatible with this server.

General rule: No downgrade. On top, restoring on express is generally possibly problematic due to the limitations of the express version.

So, you need to either export/script import the database, or grab yourself and install the free developer version. Ever since they made this one free there is no excuse for even the most junior developer not to work against it.

Answer (score 1):

The answer you cannot do that. You cannot downgrade a database.

As far as the work around is concerned you need to use the Import/Export wizards in SSMS to make it working.

Comment: I tried Copy , Import/Export options but still that options are not worked for me.

Comment: @PramodRaut:- Are you using the express version of SQl Server 2014?

Comment: I am using sql 2014 enterprise version

Answer (score 0):

You can't, but...
You can try Scripting your 2014 database and execute the Scripts on a blank 2012 database.
To open the Generate and Publish Scripts Wizard: In Object Explorer, expand Databases, right-click a database, point to Tasks, and then click Generate Scripts. Follow the steps in the Wizard to script all database's objects.
Note the disk space required.

Answer (score 0):

You can script schema and data.  See the following article:
https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2810/how-to-migrate-a-sql-server-database-to-a-lower-version/